# EXCEL : Circular reference issue

Tags: excel

I want to check the value of the current cell
if it's null then generate a random number
else keep it as it is.

```
=IF(P4<>0,RANDBETWEEN(1,100),P4)
```

but when I open the sheet I get an issue of circular reference and the value of P4 is changing even though old value is not null

Comment: You will get a circular reference if the cell containing the formula refers to itself. Null is also not the same as 0 though your test, by description, was for is null (not <>. I am assuming that bit was where you were trying the test for Null). Null in this case would be "".

Comment: You could use VBA and selection change event to perform the test and change. And now you have an example! With change event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet tab, View Code).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If not intersect(Target, Range("P4")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Range("P4") = vbNullString Then
            Range("P4") = Application.RandBetween(1, 100)
        End If
    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```